# How to find an element is enabled or not using selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests

I have used following code and currently my button is disabled.So code should return values as "false". But it is displaying value as "true".How to handle this one? I have used element attribute is "ID".[image]

```
boolean val1 = fb.Element(ObjSWchat.chatunavailableicon).isEnabled();
                    System.out.println(val1);
                    if (val1=true) {
                        fb.ValidateTest(true, "Element is enabled");
                    } else {
                        fb.ValidateTest(true, "Element is disabled");
                        Assert.assertFalse(true);
                    }
```

***HTML code:***

```
<div id="enableChat" style="display: clock;">
                    <div id="EnableChat" class="xxxx_softwaredata iconchat">
                        <div id="myChatLinkContainer" class="rn_ConditionalChatLink">
                            <div id="myChatLink" class="">
                                <div id="myChatLinkInfo" class="">

                                <!-- -->
                                <span>Unavailable</span></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Is this some button that is not enabled or not clickable?

Comment: what is the output of your code.

Comment: Yes.Button not enabled and not clickable.

Comment: @cruisepandey output i'm getting as as "True". But it should return as "False".Because here element is "Disabled", so the value should be "False".How to get val1= false ??

Answer (score 1):

First of all here is the error:

```
if (val1=true) {
```

should be

```
if (val1==true) {
```

Try to use this wait:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, timeoutInSeconds);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id<locator>));
```

or

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id<locator>));
```

Hope this would help,

Comment: You are totally right @DebanjanB, but main concern is beside waiter, this if "val=true".

Answer (score 0):

You have used the assignment operator(Single = is mentioned) and hence it is returning as true. Please change your if condition as below(specify == )

```
            if (val1==true) {
                    fb.ValidateTest(true, "Element is enabled");
                } else {
                    fb.ValidateTest(true, "Element is disabled");
                    Assert.assertFalse(true);
                }
```

Comment: I have tried as above(i.e used ==),                                                                     
              boolean val1 = fb.Element(ObjSWchat.chatunavailableicon).isEnabled();                    above code returning value as "True". But it should return as "False".Because here element is "Disabled", so the value should be "False".How to get val1= false ??

Comment: Can you share the html for the above disabled button?

Comment: added HTML content in the question